# Will Pro Tools remember the pan automation, if

Tags: pro-tools, panning, automation

I hope you can help. I am working on a film on Pro Tools 11, and will continue on a Pro Tools HD afterwards.

I have a question regarding panning automation -

There's a mono audio track. It is sending in to a stereo bus. This means I can pan the mono track .

When I switch to HD, I would like to change the stereo bus into a LCR bus.

THe question is: Will the panning automation in the mono audio track remain??

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're doing is changing the output bus to a higher channel count, it should keep the panning information and spread it across the new channel layout appropriately.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the "Center" knob on the LCR panning will tell ProTools whether you want sound to pan LCR or LR with a phantom center.  If you know that you want LR only you can always make a stereo sub buss of you LCR buss that will only have LR.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your routing it should be fine. So you're going from your mono (and possibly some stereo) tracks (dia, sfx, bg..) into the appropriate aux (dia aux, sfx aux, bg aux...). When you get to the hd rig you'll add an LCR aux that will be fed from all your stereo auxes to your speaker output.